# How do I make Flash dynamic text field <a> links fire events on mouseover?

Tags: html, flash, events, actionscript, hyperlink

Question says it all really, but I don't mind if any answers are AS2 or AS3 solutions, just curious really - seems weird that I couldn't find out how to do this really quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AS2**

If your using a dynamic text field I assume your filling it with html content. Since this is pure html inside the field it doesn't have a relation between the event model and the html. You need to have an object to access the event model in AS2.

**AS3**

But in AS3 you can use the event keyword in the href.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#event:link

http://troyworks.com/blog/2008/03/14/flash-textfield-actionscript-hyperlink-in-as30/

Comment: Thanks very much for that, I suspected as much for AS2, stoked about the AS3 solution.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you add an event listener to it? Or perhaps set the htmlText's event and handle the event as it arises. Some information can be found [here](https://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/2/langref/flash/text/TextField.html) and also [here](http://www.developphp.com/Flash_tutorials/show_tutorial.php?tid=307).

Comment: Ooops, missed this reply, will investigate tomorrow, thank you very much for your help too!

Comment: Ok, yeh the linked tut (for AS3) said enough to make me think this was also helpful, thanks again both.